# Can one ManyToMany Field contain 2 Tables? -- Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

Can one ManyToMany Field contain 2 Tables? I would like to achieve like this `name_b = ManyToManyField("A, B", related_name="+", blank=True)`

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default="")
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    add_time = models.DBateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_b = ManyToManyField(???"A, B"???, related_name="+", blank=True)
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Can it be possible? Thank you so much for any advice.

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible, but you can achieve a ternary relation by defining a fourth model such that this model has a ForeignKey to each A, B and C. In this way a C instance will be related to many A and B instance pairs

Comment: @ivissani  Got it, thank you for your advice